# Логирование NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, логирование

Доброе время суток. Нужен совет более опытных разработчиков на nodejs. Пишу приложение на epxressjs. Нужен простой логер, но что бы умел:

1. Запись логов пользователей и приложения отдельно.
2. Логи пользователей в БД (mongodb), логи приложения в файлы.
3. Логи приложения записываются каждый день в новый файл
4. Для пользовательских логов свои уровни
5. Настройка формата отображения логов (уровень, время, сообщение)

Буду очень признателен за помощь)))

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [log4js](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node). Из фич:

- coloured console logging to stdout or stderr
- file appender, with configurable log rolling based on file size or
  date
- SMTP appender
- GELF appender
- Loggly appender
- Logstash (UDP and HTTP) appender
- logFaces (UDP and HTTP) appender
- multiprocess appender (useful when you've got multiple servers)
- a logger for connect/express servers
- configurable log message layout/patterns
- different log levels for different log categories (make some parts of your app log as DEBUG, others only ERRORS, etc.)

У них даже есть [пример](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/examples/slack-appender.js) слэк-аппендера!

Существуют также [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) и [npmlog](https://github.com/npm/npmlog) (и много других), но их я не пробовал.